# Pass data object to a UITableViewCell and use it from within custom cell controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have a basic method for populating a tableView with a custom cell in Swift

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let object = array[UInt(indexPath!.row)] as Word
    var cell:DictionaryTableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dictionaryCell") as DictionaryTableViewCell
    cell.originalText.text = object.original
    return cell
}
```

Works fine. Now, I got a custom cell `DictionaryTableViewCell` with custom properties and some IBActions (for different buttons inside that cell).

My question is: How do I expose data that was passed to the cell from tableView and use it from **inside my custom cell** controller? For instance I would like to be able to manipulate it for each cell using IBActions.

For now my custom cell controller is nothing fancy

```
class DictionaryTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var originalText: UILabel!
    @IBAction func peak(sender: AnyObject) {

    }
}
```

Is there a custom property I can use to recover data passed onto it? Or do I have to implement some sort of a protocol? If so - how?

Comment: calling cell.originalText.text = object.original should show object.original's value in the cell. If you want to notify the tableview that the peak button was pressed in a cell that requires a protocol/delegate paradigm. If you just want the peak button to do something to originalText, you can manipulate the text in the peak method.